# SwiftUI Picker not changing bounded value - is binding ok?

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a view with

```
@State var myTask:MyTask
let priorities = ["","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]

var body: some View{
    VStack{
           Picker("",selection: $myTask.priority) {
                ForEach(priorities.reversed(), id:\.self){
                   Text($0)
                }
           }
           Text(myTask.priority)
    }
}
```

where MyTask is a class with priority as a String variable.

For some reason choosing a different value in the picker doesn't change the value in priority.

Help?

EDIT:

The only important part of MyTask class is :

```
class MyTask:Identifiable,Codable{
    var priority:String = ""
    
}
```

Are we allowed to bind to a child's variable?

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't tell if the `Binding` is "ok" without seeing the class `MyTask`.

Comment: A class (reference type) doesn't update the view. Use a struct or make the class *observable*

Comment: yes, that was the problem, put it as a solution vadian and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem (as *vadian* stated above) is that without conforming to Observable, MyTask isn't going to be able to update the view. Add on that conformance so that it looks like this:

```swift
class MyTask: Identifiable, Observable{
    var priority:String = ""
    
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of making this class conform to `Codable`? Also wouldn't you be looking for `ObservableObject` not `Observable`. Also for the string wouldn't a `Published` variable be useful?

Comment: @cole The original asker made it conform to `Codable` when they asked the question... `ObservableObject` might work, but the original asker also said that `Observable` worked. A `Published` variable would also work.

Comment: It's seems a bit more `SwiftUI`, utilizing what's available is always nice. As for `Codable`, I don't see this being decoded or encoded though, correct me if I'm wrong? It's not really needed just for a Picker. Explained in documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker)

Comment: You're right - I edited and removed `Codable`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a couple ways, with a `StateObject` or an `ObservableObject` class.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = "A"
    private var priorities = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Selection", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(priorities.reversed(), id: \.self) { priority in
                Text(priority)
            }
        }
        Text(selection)
    }
}
```

```swift
class MyTask: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selection = "A"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var task = MyTask()
    private var priorities = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Selection", selection: $task.selection) {
            ForEach(priorities.reversed(), id: \.self) { priority in
                Text(priority)
            }
        }
        Text(task.selection)
    }
}
```

[image: picker]